# How to create selectable tags with RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

I want to create tags using RecyclerView that can be selected to produce results.

[image]

What I want to achieve is when I tap on Books TextView on the top-right must change to Books immediately. In my case when I tap on Books it just stays in Art and it replaces Art with Books only when I replace my fragments. I also highlight buttons when clicked (changing border from grey to black) but after changing fragments highlights return back to Art again. Shortly I want to highlight button when clicked and change TextView content based on clicked button text. I partly achieved it by using interfacews but didn't get what I wanted. I provided codes below:

TrendCategoryTagsAdapter.java:

```
public class TrendCategoryTagsAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<CategorySelection, TrendCategoryTagsAdapter.TrendCategoryTagsHolder> {

    Context context;
    onCategoryTagClicked onCategoryTagClicked;

    int row_index;

    public TrendCategoryTagsAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<CategorySelection> options, Context context, com.rajabmammadli.paragrafredesign.Interface.onCategoryTagClicked onCategoryTagClicked) {
        super(options);
        this.context = context;
        this.onCategoryTagClicked = onCategoryTagClicked;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final TrendCategoryTagsHolder holder, final int position, @NonNull CategorySelection model) {
        holder.categoryNameText.setText(model.getCategoryName());

        holder.categoryNameContainer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                row_index = position;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        if (row_index == position) {
            holder.categoryNameContainer.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.black_rounded_bg));
            onCategoryTagClicked.onTagClick(holder.categoryNameText.getText().toString());
        } else {
            holder.categoryNameContainer.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.grey_rounded_bg));
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public TrendCategoryTagsHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.trendcategory_cell, parent, false);
        return new TrendCategoryTagsAdapter.TrendCategoryTagsHolder(v);
    }

    public static class TrendCategoryTagsHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        RelativeLayout categoryNameContainer;
        TextView categoryNameText;

        public TrendCategoryTagsHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            categoryNameContainer = itemView.findViewById(R.id.categoryNameContainer);
            categoryNameText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.categoryNameText);
        }
    }

}
```

trendcategory_cell.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/categoryNameContainer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/grey_rounded_bg">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/categoryNameText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/gilroyregular"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:text="categoryname"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

TrendingFragment.java:

```
public class TrendingFragment extends Fragment implements onCategoryTagClicked {

    RecyclerView trendingCategoryRV;
    TextView noPostTV, selectedCategoryText;

    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    CollectionReference categoryRef;
    String selectedCategory = "Art";

    TrendCategoryTagsAdapter trendCategoryTagsAdapter;

    public TrendingFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_trending, container, false);

        trendPostRV = view.findViewById(R.id.trendPostRV);
        trendingCategoryRV = view.findViewById(R.id.trendingCategoryRV);
        noPostTV = view.findViewById(R.id.noPostTV);
        selectedCategoryText = view.findViewById(R.id.selectedCategoryText);

        selectedCategoryText.setText(selectedCategory);

        setUpTrendCategoryTagsRV();
        setUpTrendingPostRV();
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        trendCategoryTagsAdapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        trendCategoryTagsAdapter.stopListening();
    }

    private void setUpTrendCategoryTagsRV() {
        categoryRef = db.collection("Categories");

        Query query = categoryRef.orderBy("categoryName", Query.Direction.ASCENDING);

        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<CategorySelection> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<CategorySelection>()
                .setQuery(query, CategorySelection.class)
                .build();

        trendCategoryTagsAdapter = new TrendCategoryTagsAdapter(options, getContext(), this);

        trendingCategoryRV.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

        final LinearLayoutManager trendingTagsLM = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        trendingCategoryRV.setLayoutManager(trendingTagsLM);
        trendingCategoryRV.setAdapter(trendCategoryTagsAdapter);
        trendCategoryTagsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTagClick(String categoryName) {
        selectedCategory = categoryName;
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried to update the "options" object with the new Query object and star listening again? Does it work that way?

Comment: @AlexMamo I tried but unfortunately no result